# I have an error in Run of an App in android influtter

Tags: flutter

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\anjana\flutter_windows_2.5.3-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\anjana\flutter_windows_2.5.3-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I need time get an method to resolve it
I have tried pub get pub upgrade flutter pub upgrade --main versions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no way of narrowing down your specific problem, I can recommend trying to create a new flutter project and copying your lib over.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CMD :

1. Invalidate cache & restart
2. flutter clean
3. flutter pub get

then try to build again.